# Pass string array to method

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C++, I have used C before but never used C++. This is one of my first programs, and it's supposed to do something really simple, however I'm unable to even pass strings between methods... When I call the method `setMode` with a string array, the method instance recieves an empty array, and not the one I've sent. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define LED_PATH "sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr"

class LED{

    private:
        string path;
        int number;

    public:
        LED(int number);
        virtual void setMode(string mode[]);
        virtual ~LED();
};


LED::LED(int number){
    ostringstream fs;
    this->number = number;
    fs << LED_PATH << number;
    this->path = string(fs.str());

    cout << this->path << endl;
}

LED::~LED(){

}

void LED::setMode(string mode[]){
    //Will use all fields of mode[] in the future
    cout << "setMode: mode: " << mode[0].c_str() << endl;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    LED LEDs[4] = {LED(0), LED(1), LED(2), LED(3)};
    string mode[argc-1];

    //TODO Perform argc value safety check
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        mode[i] = string(argv[i]);
        cout << mode[i].c_str()<<endl;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            LEDs[i].setMode(mode);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/LED_Cpp$ ./led on 1
sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0
sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr1
sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr2
sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr3
on
1
setMode: mode:
setMode: mode:
setMode: mode:
setMode: mode:
```

Comment: don't use arrays, use `std::vector` or similar in c++

Comment: Also, why are you passing the whole array, when `setMode()` only needs a single `string` parameter?

Comment: The method is not yet implemented, it will used the whole array in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> string mode[argc-1];
> ```

This uses a **proprietary GCC extension**. In standard C++, a raw array's size must be known at compile time.

You need something like this instead:

> ```
> if (argc < 4) {
>     std::cerr << "error\n";
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
> }
> string mode[4];
> ```

Or, what would be **very much preferable**, use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> mode(argc-1);
```

> ```
> for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
>     mode[i] = string(argv[i]);
>     cout << mode[i].c_str()<<endl;
> }
> ```

This will leave `mode[0]` empty.

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
>         LEDs[i].setMode(mode);
> }
> ```

The array (or `std::vector`) passed to `setMode` will thus always be such that the first element is an empty string.

> ```
> void LED::setMode(string mode[]){
> ```

This is an attempt to pass an array to a function. What happens really is that a pointer to the first element is passed and the **size information is lost**.

The correct way of passing a raw array including its size information would be to use a reference:

```
 void LED::setMode(string (&mode)[4])
```

But as I mentioned previously, just use a `std::vector` and you'll be fine. When you need to modify the vector, pass it via `&`, else via `const&`:

```
 void LED::setMode(std::vector<std::string> const& mode)
```

In either case, inside of the method, you currenly just access the first element:

> ```
> cout << "setMode: mode: " << mode[0].c_str() << endl;
> ```

As we've established before, `mode[0]` is always empty. That's why nothing is printed.

Answer (score 2):

You are off by one. You are writing to

```
mode[1]
```

in

```
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    mode[i] = string(argv[i]);
```

and you use

```
mode[0]
```

for output.